# How to show Separator line for currently displaying cells in the UITableView using MonoTouch?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I have showing 5 to 8 items in the `UITableView`. But `Separator` line showing empty cells also. There are no value on that empty cells.  Why `Separator` line showing on these empty cells?  I choose the `Separator` value is `Single Line` in Interface Builder. How to show `Separator` line for currently displaying cells in the `UITableView` using MonoTouch?

Look at the screenshot. I have showing 5 items in the `UITableView`. But separator showing all the cells of `UITableView`. I need separator line for used cells in the `UITableView`.

[image: look at the screen shot]

Comment: Can you show the code you used ? You might also want to look at MonoTouch.Dialogs which makes using tables so much easier @ https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog

Comment: @poupou: I have used like [this sample code](http://sabonrai.wordpress.com/2009/08/28/monotouch-sample-code-uitableview/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to eliminate empty cells from your `UITableView`?
If yes, do this to clear out the empty cells/space below your data:

```
/// <summary>
/// Removes empty lines below a tableview. Attention: calls the table's delegate implicitly, so make sure it is initialized.
/// </summary>
public static void ClearEmptyTableViewSpacers ( UITableView oTableView )
{
    UIView oViewSpacerClear = new UIView (new System.Drawing.RectangleF (0, 0, oTableView.Frame.Width, 10));
    oViewSpacerClear.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
    oTableView.TableFooterView = oViewSpacerClear;
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question with screenshot. Just look at my question.

Comment: Then my code will fix it. Just place it in ViewDidLoad() after your TableView was initialized. Just give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to say a seperator line only for special cells. The tableview always draws seperator lines for the complete height of the UITableView.

The only way to made this possible is to set the TableView SeperatorColor to Transparent and draw the Seperator Line within a Cell. But i think that's heavily drain performance on large lists.